# Why isn't my utf8 working in my php page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wampserver, navicat

I searched for a lot of answers here but i still have a problem with the UTF8. "Special" letters doesn't appear in my browser. 
I'm using: 
php Designer 8
Wampserver 3.1.4_x86
MySQL 5.6
Navicat100_premium
I'm using Google

[[image: This is what appears in my page]
those "?" are all "çççççççç"

This is the beginning of the code:

```
<html>
<title> APPACDM </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: *"I searched for a lot of answers here"* ... Did you find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279)? - it's pretty much the defacto answer to every UTF-8 issue you could possibly experience.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help you better?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks in the wrong order to me. If this is a HTML page with embedded PHP try this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> APPACDM </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Note: always set your PHP Header response *before* any HTML output. Always wrap PHP in PHP tags, not plain text as in your example.

See here: [PHP Header command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: You might also need to look at HTTP response codes as well.

Comment: ... and you've fixed the structurally broken HTML for free as well ;)

Comment: Yes focus on doing the basics well, that's what I always tell the junior devs in my team.

Comment: Still not working, is it the versions that aren't compatible?

Comment: I don't yet have enough information to answer your question; I am only able to correct what I see.

Answer (score 0):

If this data is queried from a database then you can do the following:  
[PDO version]

```
$bdd->exec("set names utf8");
```

[MYSQLI version]

```
mysqli_set_charset($bdd, "utf8");
```